# Example values(placeholder) for query parameters in Swagger (swashbuckle)

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, parameters, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using swashbuckle in net core to create a swagger documented API.

The function I have uses query parameters. I wanted to add a short description for each query parameter, next to the textbox where the parameter value is entered. I achieved this by using XML comments:

```
/// <param name="propertyId">The integration property ID. Events related to presentations related to this ID will be returned</param>
public ActionResult GetEvents([BindRequired] string propertyId){}
```

This works fine, but it also adds the description text in the textbox placeholder:
[image]

I saw that the placeholder can be changed, if the generated JSON has an 'example' value for the query parameter. How do I add the example value, or change the placeholder in general using the XML comments or something similar?

Comment: So you want a placeholder value yeah?

Comment: Yes, or at least to remove the description text from the textbox field and make it empty :) 
Right now it looks like it is composed of the Name + Description

Answer (score 5):

You can try to add `example="xxx"` into `<param></param>` to add the example value and change the placeholder.

```
  /// <param name="propertyId" example="id">The integration property ID. Events related to presentations related to this ID will be returned</param>
        public IActionResult GetEvents([BindRequired] string propertyId) {
            ...
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: One more question, what if the parameter is of type DateTime? Setting a string in the example that way does not work, only possibilities that did work were example = " " (sets placeholder to starting date) and example = "2021-12-12" (sets it do datetime in the yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss format). Is there a way to use string as the placeholder here?

Comment: I realized that this does provide an example value, but it does not change the placeholder. https://prnt.sc/23a7e8y
If I were to click try it out, the text value would be there, and I need it to be empty, with a custom placeholder

Comment: To use examples add: 
`using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` + 
`services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblies(typeof(SomeController).Assembly)` and use minimum Swagger V3.

Comment: @Yoro, i thought you could only use the `AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblies` for request/response objects and not querystring requests?

Comment: Does anyone know how to use an example for a List<> query parameter?

Comment: @kubo i know this is late but looking at the code: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/8f363f7359cb1cb8fa5de5195ec6d97aefaa16b3/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/XmlComments/XmlCommentsRequestBodyFilter.cs#L53

if you just put it in as a json array string in the example="[&quot;test&quot;,&quot;test2&quot;]" may work